# Problem starting httpd - Could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:443

Tags: apache, ssl, centos7, httpd.conf

When I try to restart httpd, I get the following error, viewed at /var/log/httpd/error_log:

```
[Tue Sep 13 16:32:12.154638 2022] [core:crit] [pid 3255] (22)Invalid argument: AH00069: make_sock: for address [::]:443, apr_socket_opt_set: (IPV6_V6ONLY)
(98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:443
(98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:443
```

So I used the following code to see if Listen 443 was used more than once, but I get the following response:

```
$ sudo grep '443' -r /etc/httpd/conf.d/*
/etc/httpd/conf.d/corona-web-app.conf:<VirtualHost *:443>
/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf:Listen 443 https
/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf:#NameVirtualHost *:443
/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf:#<VirtualHost _default_:443>
/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf:##ServerName www.example.com:443
```

This is hosted in Amazon LightSail, so firewall is managed through the networking option directly in the site. Still, ports that are opened are: 22, 80, 443 (SSH, http, https).
So yeah, I'm a bit lost, some information that may be useful:

httpd version

```
$ sudo httpd -v
Server version: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS)
Server built:   Mar 24 2022 14:57:57
```

OS

```
$ cat /etc/os-release
NAME="CentOS Linux"
VERSION="7 (Core)"
ID="centos"
ID_LIKE="rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="7"
PRETTY_NAME="CentOS Linux 7 (Core)"
ANSI_COLOR="0;31"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:centos:centos:7"
HOME_URL="https://www.centos.org/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.centos.org/"

CENTOS_MANTISBT_PROJECT="CentOS-7"
CENTOS_MANTISBT_PROJECT_VERSION="7"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="centos"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION="7"
```

php version

```
$ php -v
PHP 5.4.16 (cli) (built: Apr  1 2020 04:07:17)
Copyright (c) 1997-2013 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.5, Copyright (c) 1999-2015, by Zend Technologies
```

Any help or idea is welcome. Thanks!

Comment: Its saying port 443 is already in use. Please check who is already listening on port 443 using `netstat -tulapan | grep 443`

Answer (score 0):

Had this issue after patching RedHat 7,  Server version: Apache/2.4.6 (Red Hat Enterprise Linux)

Renaming the ssl.conf file corrected the issue